# Error: findComponentRoot when using divs

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using react and redux but I'm getting the following Exception:

> foo.js:10 Uncaught Error: findComponentRoot(..., .0.$data.0.0.$22): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a  when using tables, nesting tags like `<form>`, `<p>`, or `<a>`, or using non-SVG elements in an  parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID

when I press on the button below:

```
let mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const user = state.user.get("user");
    return {
        data: state.data.get("data"),
        loading: state.pausedAlarms.get("loading"),
        userId: user&&user.id
    }
};

let mapActionsToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getData() {
            dispatch(getData());
        },
        selectUser(user){
            dispatch(selectUser(user));
        },
    };
};

let Foo = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props["getData"]();
    },
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {

        if(nextProps["userId"] !== this.props["userId"]) {
            nextProps["getData"]();
        }
        return true;
    },
    render() {
        const {
            data,
            selectUser,
            loading
        } = this.props;

        if (loading) {
            return (
                <div id="3" key="3">LOADING</div>
            );
        }
        else if (data){
            return (
                <div id="1" key="1">

                    <div id="11" key="11">
                        HEADER
                    </div>

                    <button
                        id="2"
                        key="22"
                        onClick={
                            e => {
                                selectUser(new User({id:1,name:"Foo"}))
                            }
                        }
                    >Click</button>
                </div>
            );
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

Pressing the button dispatches the action selectUser, which updates my redux state with a new value for `userId`. This causes shouldComponentUpdate to call `nextProps["getData"]();`. The action `getData` begins by dispatching such that `loading` is set to true in the reducer.

The code above renders as expected its just that I'm seeing an exception in the console window.

If I do the following instead:

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {

```
        if(nextProps["userId"] !== this.props["userId"]) {
            nextProps["getData"]();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    },
```

my code works as expected but without the exception. 
What am I doing wrong? How might I debug this problem?

Comment: What does `selectUser` do?

Comment: @Timo It dispatches a redux action resulting in state.user.set("user", user)

Comment: @Timo The changing of this state will result in nextProps["getData"]() being called in shouldComponentUpdate.

Comment: @Baz Does the answer below solves your problem? if not I will take a swing at it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is caused that you are dispatching an action in `shouldComponentUpdate`.

You can dispatch it in `componentWillReceiveProps`:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps["userId"] !== this.props["userId"]) {
        nextProps["getData"]();
    }
}
```

`shouldComponentUpdate` is intended to determine whether a component should be updated, instead of updating the state. Take a look at the following SO discussion:

> [Is it OK to call setState from within shouldComponentUpdate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290189/is-it-ok-to-call-setstate-from-within-shouldcomponentupdate)

---

**Update 1**

Check if the problem is caused by the render structure. Try to simplify it (remove keys, mouniting/unmounting nodes and so on):

```
getData() {
    return (
        <div>
            HEADER
            <button onClick={ e => { selectUser(new User({id:1,name:"Foo"})) } }>Click</button>
        </div>
    );
}

render() {
    const {
        data,
        selectUser,
        loading
    } = this.props;

    return (
        <div>
            { loading ? 'LOADING' : null }
            { (! loading) && data ? this.getData() : null }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I know this answer makes perfect sense on the usage of `componentWillReceiveProps` and `shouldComponentUpdate`. But I would like to know whether this really solves the OP.

Comment: @Baz check if the problem is caused by the render structure. Check my answer for details.